# How can I get access to my Google Analytics control panel again?

Tags: google-workspace, google-analytics, google-account

Recently, I migrated one of my domains to full Google Accounts. As my main account had been used for Google Analytics before, I renamed my existing me@mydomain.com Google Account to oldme@mydomain.com . Then I migrated my domain, creating a new me@mydomain.com Google Account from my Google Apps account.

Logging into Google Analytics now with oldme@mydomain.com, I wanted to make me@mydomain.com a adminstrator for the Google Analytics account, so I went into the settings. It hadn't updated to reflect the account name change, so while oldme@mydomain.com was the adminstrator and had full privileges, the user list only had me@mydomain.com on it. I just clicked save, guessing this would correctly replace oldme@mydomain.com with me@mydomain.com, however, the edit link disappeared afterwards. I figured this was because it had succeeded and me@mydomain.com was the adminstrator.

So I attempted to log into Google Analytics with me@mydomain.com , and got stuck at the account creation process. At te site prompt, I entered in mydomain.com, and the final page just shows "An error has occured".

Has anyone encountered this issue before, and how do I fix it? I can still read the stats with oldme@mydomain.com but I can't change anything.

Answer (score 2):

Fill out the form here:

https://spreadsheets.google.com/a/google.com/viewform?formkey=dGRvcXVVNU5HbXhSSldRNU5LWVR6Vmc6MQ&ndplr=1

You should get a response in a couple of days.

You can also try emailing analytics-support@google.com but that has not delivered good results for me in the past.. Maybe you will be lucky?

Comment: I filled out the form, the asked me for more details and then never responded. I've changed my domain so I just made a fresh start with stats and use the old broken account when I need to look at historical stats.